# VS2013 - Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework… - Error

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I was having issues with VS2013 and I had to reinstall it. Now when trying to  create an entity data model with Oracle i get this error "*Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework..*"

[image]

I am connecting to **Oracle 21c**.

I have installed **Oracle ODTwithODAC122010**.

I have Changed **Active Solution Platform to 32 Bit from AnyCPU**

Do I need to install these from Nuget manager?

- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

MY *references*.

[image]

Web.config

[image]

Comment: Find out which .Net version your Oracle packages support. Then downgrade your project to exactly this version.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your suggestion. I installed "ODAC 12.2c Release 1..."  http://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/utilsoft-086879.html

Comment: If you compile a project in Visual Studio you can choose the so called <Target Framework>. In your case I would try 4 and 4.5 and see if your Oracle software is compatible with this .Net Framework versions.